# Invoking DataService from wso2 ESB with secure port

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I just want to invoke a secure DataService endpoint from wso2 ESB and I couldn't find the right and straight forward solution.
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11449159/invoking-secured-web-services-using-wso2-esb) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171995/invoking-https-end-point-from-wso2-esb) but no success!
I define my endpoint in ESB as folows:
WSDL Endpoint:
WSDL URI: http://[myIP]:7763/services/PostPaidProviders?wsdl

Service: PostPaidProviders

Port: SecureSOAP11Endpoint

FYI, if I change my Port to 'SOAP11Endpoint' my proxy service on ESB works properly.
Thanks

Comment: I've imported my WSO2-DSS's certificate to my ESB keystore from configuration->KeyStores but it still does not work.
It seems that it can not validate the host name! I still need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've imported my WSO2-DSS's certificate to my ESB keystore from configuration->KeyStores but it still does not work. It seems that it can not validate the host name!
The error was this: "error: Host name verification failed for [MyHostName]"

I added following parameter to the `<transportSender name="https` part of /repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml file, restarted the server and it worked :)

```
<parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>
```